# dygraphs only take sorted data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dygraphs

I am trying to build scatterplots using `dygraphs`. The scales I get are not correct and I'm wondering if it is because `dygraphs` expects sorted data along the x-axis.

This [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chapo/pc1d58ck/6/) seems to show that it is the case.

All help welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just answering my own question because other people might need it.

It is indeed the case that giving non x-axis-sorted data to `dygraphs` throws it for a loop.

So when doing scatterplots, the data needs to be sorted before being used for the graphs.